# How to Share NSURLConnection credentials with Safari?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential, nsurlcredentialstorage

I'm trying to intercept link and login a user, then send them on to Safari and have the page load with no authentication request.

So, what I'm doing so far...

I register a custom URL scheme for my app. Call it "myhttp". Now someone clicks on a link (say from an email) of myhttp://secured.com/foo and my app runs. The apps pulls the user's credentials from somewhere and makes a call to the real URL with an `NSURLConnection`. The `NSURLConectionDelegate` implements `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` and I navigate through the security layer fine. Next I try loading the same url using the `UIApplication` `openURL` method to bring up Safari, but I still get an authentication check.

I thought this would work because I read the follow in the Apple documentation.

`Credentials stored in persistent storage are kept in the user’s keychain and shared among all apps.`

And when I check the `NSURLCredentialStorage` I can see the credentials I just used stored there with the correct information, protection space, scheme, etc, but clearly I'm doing something wrong or I wouldn't be getting an authentication challenge when I switch to Safari.

So the question is, did I just screw up somewhere along the line, forget some important bit or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't possible before iOS 8, but is now with the [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/) feature.

> Add a `com.apple.developer.associated-domains` entitlement to your app.
>   This entitlement must include all the domains with which you want to
>   share credentials.
>
> Add an `apple-app-site-association` file to your website. This file must
>   include application identifiers for all the apps with which the site
>   wants to share credentials, and it must be properly signed.
>
> When the app is installed, the system downloads and verifies the site
>   association file for each of its associated domains. If the
>   verification is successful, the app is associated with the domain.
>
> An app can share credentials with any associated domains by calling
>   `SecAddSharedWebCredential` and `SecRequestSharedWebCredential`.

Comment: And just to clarify why this is the case, the comment in the docs about credentials being shared is very out of date.  It applies only to OS X, not to iOS.  In OS X, the keychain is shared, and ACLs limit which apps can access each item.  If an app asks to use a cred that it doesn't have the ability to access, the OS asks the user for permission.  In iOS, the keychain is basically per-app (with various exceptions, such as keychain access groups).